# C++ Pointers take up more memory than an integer?

Tags: c++, pointers

I thought that pointers took up less memory, and were more efficient but when I use sizeof() on a pointer, it says it uses twice the memory as an integer. What am I missing here? Here's my code

```
  int p = 1;
  Int a = 1;
  Int *pointera;
  pointera= &p;
  cout << sizeof(pointera) << endl;
  cout << sizeof(a) << endl;
```

It says "a" takes up 4 bytes and "pointera" takes up 8. Shouldn't the pointer tak up less? What am I missing

Comment: You just thought wrong.

Comment: Why would a pointer take up less memory than an integer???

Comment: What? I was told that pointers are more efficient?

Comment: Efficient in what sense?

Comment: More memory efficient. It was faster in run time, and was more lightweight.

Comment: Sure, and tomatoes are more efficient than tangerines.

Comment: Variables cannot be "faster in run time". Code can.

Comment: don't believe everything you were told

Comment: @M.M but wait, what if I shouldn't believe _that_?

Comment: Ok, so sizeof was just stating the amount of memory that the pointer was in reference to?

Comment: @ClassifiedClassified: Yes, It is the amount of memory pointer occupying.

Comment: @denis thank you. Thenewbostin didn't explain pointers very well. Salt

Comment: If you got the answer to your question you can select the correct symbol below the answer. That way people will know that this question have been answered.

Comment: Ok @denis thanks, I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pointer contains a memory address. When you call the sizeof on a pointer it gives the size of the address. In a 64 bit computer a memory address would be 8 bytes.

Example

```
int *pointera = &p;
sizeof(pointera);
```

Here `pointera` stores the memory address of `p`. This address is 64 bit which means 8 bytes.

size of int, double and char are different but if you calculate the size of pointer of these data types than they would all be of same size in the same computer.

Comment: perhaps also worth mentioning the size of an int depends on the data model

Comment: Yes, data model used by compiler determines the size of fundamental types and it affects the size of pointer also.

Comment: some systems may use different sizes for pointers to different things